# Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) file.d.ts(49, 17): An argument for 'options' was not provided

Tags: typescript

i made a example code to download a word file on click of a button in typescript, here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Document, Packer } from "docx";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
function App() {
  function saveDocumentToFile(doc, fileName) {
    const packer = new Packer();
    const mimeType ="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
    const docblob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, mimeType);
    saveAs(docblob, fileName);
  });
}

function generateWordDocument(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let doc = new Document();
  saveDocumentToFile(doc, "New Document.docx");
}

return (
 <div className="App">
 <button onClick={generateWordDocument}>Generate Word Document</button>
 </div>
);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

and i got error on the "**line let doc = new Document();**" saying "(alias) new Document(options: IPropertiesOptions, fileProperties?: IFileProperties | undefined): Document
import Document
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
file.d.ts(49, 17): An argument for 'options' was not provided."

this is the full error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCL8h.png)

can someone help to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error pretty much means what it says. `new Document()` isn't enough. You need to pass options, and you didn't. Meaning you can't have `()` with nothing there between the parenthesis. More information is needed, and you aren't providing it.

Here's an example from [the documentation page](https://docx.js.org/#/):

```
const doc = new Document({
    sections: [{
        properties: {},
        children: [
            new Paragraph({
                children: [
                    new TextRun("Hello World"),
                    new TextRun({
                        text: "Foo Bar",
                        bold: true,
                    }),
                    new TextRun({
                        text: "\tGithub is the best",
                        bold: true,
                    }),
                ],
            }),
        ],
    }],
});
```

Comment: i just to want to download a empty word document when the button is pressed, so what should i pass as a argument ? i tried this code snippet in codesandbox, it worked there but in vs code its showing error. @kshetline

Comment: If `new Document()` actually works, but VSCode is enforcing a type signature that doesn't allow it, you can try `new (Document as any)()`.

Comment: thanks that actually did the trick